# get query on JSON in WEB2PY

Tags: javascript, json, web2py

I'm using the framework web2py, I creating file JSON in `default.py` and after I call it in my file `.js` now I wanted to get the query in my file JSON but it doesn't work.

I have a function in my file `.js` that get the query (like this):

```
function createQueryCityName(strUser) { 
    var query = new google.visualization.Query ("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ecobayes_reporting/default/call/json/get_data_physics");
    //var query = new google.visualization.Query ("http://api.batisense.com/batisense/datasource?table=montmorin");
    console.log(query);
    query.setQuery("select building_name");
    console.log(query);
    //return query;
    //query.send(drawTable);
}
```

and after it sends the query to another function like this:

```
function drawTable(query) {
   /* 
    if (query.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + query.getMessage() + ' ' + query.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
    }
   */
    console.log(query);
    var data = query.getDataTable();
    //var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data);
}
```

but I don't know why it doesn't work. In my console I have this:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ecobayes_reporting/static/js/jquery-1.10.0.min.map 404 (NOT FOUND) index:198
ls {jf: "auto", tj: false, Mg: Object, sj: false, rj: "http://api.batisense.com/batisense/datasource?table=montmorin"…}
 PhysicsReports.js:38
ls {jf: "auto", tj: false, Mg: Object, sj: false, rj: "http://api.batisense.com/batisense/datasource?table=montmorin"…}
 PhysicsReports.js:40
Event {clipboardData: undefined, cancelBubble: false, returnValue: true, srcElement: document, defaultPrevented: false…}
 PhysicsReports.js:51
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Event> has no method 'getDataTable' PhysicsReports.js:52
```

Comment: what does the generated JSON look like? Seems to me that your JSON doesn't have the data it's expected to have by the google visualisation tool (which I'm not familiar with)

Comment: this is my JSON :                                                        @service.json
def get_data_physics():
    data = {
    "timestamp":["2012-12-08 00:04:53", "2012-12-08 00:09:53",  11:10:32",23:55:47"],
    "outdoor":[3.6,   1.0, 1.0, 0.7, 0.7],
    "indoor":[13.2,   10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6],
    "energy":[41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0, 41966.0],
    "heating":[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "presence":["False", "False", "False", "False", "False",  
    "daylight":["False", "False", "False", "False", "False",  ],
    }
    return json.dumps(data)

Comment: I meant the final rendered JSON (i.e. what gets sent to the browser rather than the source which generates it). Also you should put this in the question not a comment, so that it can be formatted properly.

Comment: I notice a few errors though; `presence` isn't closed and there are only 3 timestamps. Also there are 7 heating values, and 2 commas near the end (maybe python lets you get away with that, I don't know)

Comment: le format the JSON is good, i delete some column because here I can't publish all of my JSON.

Comment: I can see my JSON in my browser with this address but i can't get the query on it (http://127.0.0.1:8000/ecobayes_reporting/default/call/json/get_data_physics)

Comment: no point posting a localhost address here. Anyway, looking up the plugin, it seems you're using it OK (assuming you didn't really comment out the `query.send(drawTable);` line and you're not doing funny stuff when calling the first function, or calling the second function by some method not shown here). Try putting your JSON through an online validator to be sure it isn't causing an error.